# ruby 1.9 methods in ruby 1.8.6

Tags: ruby, methods

Is there a gem or a library to get ruby 1.9 methods like

```
[1, 2, 3].combination(2)
[1, 2, 3].permutation(2)
[1, 2, 3].product([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].cycle
```

Comment: I think you mean 1.8.6, these work in 1.8.7

Comment: exactly
as all servers have 1.8.6 and I can't update ruby on all of them

Comment: Kind of like python's `from future import awesome-feature`?

Comment: sorry, but i know a little about python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly the goal of my gem [`backports`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports).

It implements in pure Ruby all the new features of Ruby 1.8.7 and many of Ruby 1.9.x and 2.0. This of course includes `#combination`, `#permutation`, `#product` and `#cycle`.

You can, for example:

```
require 'backports/1.8.7/array/combination'
[1, 2, 3].combination(2) # => works, even in Ruby 1.8.6
```

The implementation in `backports` pass most [RubySpecs](http://rubyspec.org/) (which is not the case for `facets`) to guarantee not having compatibility problems.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the 1.8.x versions of Ruby Facets (http://facets.rubyforge.org/).  Facets has become a bit of a mess (note 404s on website), but I have an old version of the gem installed (1.8.54) which has some of these pre-standard changes.

```
> gem install --version=1.8.54 facets
```

And then:

```
gem 'facets', "~>1.8"
require 'enumerator'
require 'facets/core/enumerable/cartesian_product'
require 'facets/core/enumerable/permutation'
require 'facets/core/enumerable/each_combination'

[1, 2, 3].enum_for(:each_combination,2).to_a   # note - only each form is available
[1, 2, 3].permutation(2)
[1, 2, 3].cartesian_product([1, 2, 3])         # note - rename
# Can't find .cycle equivalent after a quick search, maybe nothing there
```

You may want to alias some of these methods to get code compatibility.

Sorry, its not great.

Comment: I believe these have been renamed and moved in more recent versions. To avoid such compatibility problems, use `backports` instead (see my answer)