# ruby - Permutation between different elements in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby - Permutation between elements of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716873/ruby-permutation-between-elements-of-an-array)

I'm coding a plugin in Google Sketchup with ruby and I faced a real problem while trying to permute different elements in arrays that are present in an another array, all this depending on a user combination.

I have an array of arrays like:

```
[["a, "b", c"], ["lol1", "lol2", lol3"], ["so1", "so2", "so3"]]
```

For a combination like:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

The output should still same:

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["lol1", "lol2", "lol3"], ["so1", "so2", "so3"]]
```

But for a combination like:

```
[2, 1, 3]
```

The output should be:

```
[["b", "a", "c"], ["lol2", "lol1", "lol3"], ["so2", "so1", "so3"]]
```

But for a combination like:

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

The output should be:

```
[["c", "b", a"], ["lol3", "lol2", "lol1"], ["so3", "so2", "so1"]]
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? What code have you written?

Comment: @Mehdi Kamar, this array does not contain what you think it does. It is an Array of arrays, but each subarray contains just one string.

Comment: +! @steenslag, and, as such, this question is too localized to be answered.

Comment: @theTinMan Ruby 1.8.6 (within Google Sketchup 8). I have tried to delete the two useless strings of each array with `thearray.map do |row| row.map do row.delete_at(1) end end` two times so I keep only the first and then do a push of the two strings. But it didn't work

Comment: @steenslag How should I deal with that then ?

Comment: @MehdiKamar for splitting the strings in your case, you can try: `[["a, b, c"], ["lol1, lol2, lol3"], ["so1, so2, so3"]].map(&:first).map{|x| x.split(/,\s*/)}`

Comment: @Mark if they noticed the changes that I made, I wouldn't ask again.

Comment: @MehdiKamar the way to do this on SO is edit the original and not add a new one asking the same question

Comment: @Mark it's not the same question since I changed the arrays, also I've edited the original before adding a new one if you took the time to see that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ar = [["a, b, c"], ["lol1, lol2, lol3"], ["so1, so2, so3"]]
p maybe_this = ar.map{|sub_ar| sub_ar.first.split(', ')}
#[["a", "b", "c"], ["lol1", "lol2", "lol3"], ["so1", "so2", "so3"]]
idx = [2,1,3]
#indexing of an array is zero-based
p idx.map!{|i| i-1} #[1,0,2]
p res = maybe_this.map{|sub_ar| sub_ar.values_at(*idx)}
#[["b", "a", "c"], ["lol2", "lol1", "lol3"], ["so2", "so1", "so3"]]
```

The short story: the [values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at) method takes multiple arguments; `*idx` splats an array into multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks you saved my life!
I was wondering if I had an array containing a zero like `[0,2,1]` ?

Comment: Then don't do `idx.map!{|i| i-1} `. All the input you have to work with is (was) in a bit clumsy format. [0,2,1] is fine and needs no reworking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
perm_idx = [1,2,3].permutation.to_a.index([2,3,1])
[["a", "b", "c"], ["lol1", "lol2", "lol3"], ["so1", "so2", "so3"]].map {|x| x.permutation.to_a[perm_idx] }
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `permutation' for [1, 2, 3]:Array

Comment: @MehdiKamar I guess you're using ruby 1.8? This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150359/ruby-1-9-methods-in-ruby-1-8-6

Comment: Yes i'm using ruby 1.8.6. I'm going to check your proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want, but this might work for you:

```
a = [["a, b, c"], ["lol1, lol2, lol3"], ["so1, so2, so3"]]

def combi_with_join(ordering, arrays)
  ordering = ordering.map {|x| x - 1}
  arrays.map {|ar| [ar.first.split(/,\s*/).values_at(*ordering).join(", ")] }
end

puts combi_with_join([1, 2, 3], a).inspect
puts combi_with_join([2, 1, 3], a).inspect
puts combi_with_join([3, 2, 1], a).inspect
```

if you actually want an array of arrays...

```
def combi(ordering, arrays)
  ordering = ordering.map {|x| x - 1}
  arrays.map {|ar| ar.first.split(/,\s*/).values_at(*ordering) }
end

puts combi([1, 2, 3], a).inspect
puts combi([2, 1, 3], a).inspect
puts combi([3, 2, 1], a).inspect
```